# Can you change Angular mat-expansion-panel text/font colors?

Tags: angular

I cannot change the text color in the mat-expansion-panel?

I've got an app with a mat-expansion-panel. I can change the background colors, etc, using .mat-expansion-panel-header, but nothing i do seems to affect the text color of the title. Trying to go from the default color white background black text, to a dark blue background (which i can do) and white text (which i cannot).

I've tried varieties of options with -label, -text, and -typography, etc and no change.

```
/deep/ .mat-expansion-panel-header-label,
.mat-expansion-panel-header-label.mat-expanded,
.mat-expansion-panel-header-label.mat-expanded:hover {
  background: white;  

}
```

I've tried numerous versions of things as shown above but get nothing. The basic expectation is the text comes out white instead of black.

Comment: Which css/scss file are you targeting those classes in? Styles are scoped so it may be that you are targeting classes outside of your component.

Comment: i'm using the app.component.scss file. I've looked trying to find out of that is the case and it can't be changed there but haven't found anything on it..

Comment: If I were you I would change it in my main scss file and see if that solves the issue. If so, it is a scoping issue, and then you can decide how you want to handle it. If not then it's more likely you are targeting the classes incorrectly.

Comment: I've looked at the main, and it doesn't refer to label, it refers to typography which makes me think you're probably right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the latest version of Angular Material (7), then this should do the trick:

```
.mat-expansion-panel-header-title {
  color: red
}
```

also see the stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cnasgn